# Honda Accord 2013 steering

Tags: honda, accord, steering, power-steering

The power steering is not working well,I mean the steering is very hard to turn.  The steering is electrical what can I do to make it easier to turn.  When you are on mottion it's soft,but when you want  to make a u turn and you hold your brake and make u turn it's very strong.what can I do to it boss.

Comment: Has it suddenly got worse? was it easier on a different car? Have you checked the tire pressures? It is normally designed to be an "assistance" not "no effort required". Some of us find the amount of "assistance " is too much and miss the poor feedback from the wheels...

Comment: Is the EPS light on the dash lit?